# Is this time complexity of O(nlogn) using HeapSort

Tags: java, time-complexity, heapsort

Is this in time complexity of O(nlogn) time? If not how do I fix this

Goal: Using HeapSort supposed to find sum pairs using 1 number in each array to find a + b = c (given)

Basic HeapSort sort function

```
boolean SumPairs(int[] Arr1, int[] Arr2, int p) {

    heapSort(Arr2, p);

    int target = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Arr1.length; i++) {
        target = p - Arr1[i];
    if (BinarySearch(Arr2, target) != -1)
        return true;
  }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: You don't even show your `heapSort` function. For that matter, you don't even say what your language is. Please add an appropriate language tag.

Comment: proper indentation, please

Answer (score 1):

The average time complexity of a correctly implemented heap sort is O(NlogN); see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort.

The average time complexity of a correctly implemented binary search is O(logN); see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

So, *assuming that the methods you are calling are correctly implemented*, the average time complexity of your methods is `O(NlogN) + (O(N) * O(logN))` per call.  That reduces to `O(NlogN)`.

---

Note that this is actually a method with two array parameters, so strictly speaking, the complexity class is: `O(NlogN + MlogN)` were `M` is the length of the first array and `N` is the length of the second one.